# Fonts doesn't render in Chrome or IE in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, google-chrome

When I visit, for example, http://www.bolagsverket.se from a user account on this Windows 2008 Server, Chrome displays the site but all the text is gone. When I try in IE it's even worse, it doesn't even load the page, I jsut end up with this: http://dl.pixelstore.se/image/0y1f0y0w1J39

The fonts used for this site is (from CSS): font-family:Frutiger,Frutiger Linotype,Univers,DejaVu Sans Condensed,Liberation Sans,Nimbus Sans L,Geneva,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Tahoma,sans-serif

If I edit the CSS through Chrome Developer Tools, and erase all fonts until Arial it suddenly works.

The strange thing is that everything works fine from the administrator account, it's just (all) the user accounts that doesn't work.

My guess is that Chrome/IE is asking for the fonts but somehow they are restricted in the user account. Instead of just ignoring the fonts they can't find they try to render them anyway. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the fonts you have listed there are not default fonts in Windows, as far as I can tell.  Most likely there is a JavaScript plugin that is using a site like TypeKit to obtain those fonts.  Either way, it should fail over to the other fonts listed like Arial as you mention.  There may simply be another error somewhere along the rendering path that is causing no text to render.

Make sure the fonts in use are either installed and loaded, or that there are no JavaScript errors when you load the page.